# Does split environment allow only 2 columns?

Tags: equations, amsmath, split

The following code compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

While replacing the contents of the `split` with

```
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6
```

results in `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` It looks like `split` supports only two "columns", but I can't find any mention of that, neither in the manual nor anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), page 4:

[image: about split]

Comment: Thanks. It seems I was looking at outdated documentation: http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf

Comment: @Dmitry -- I've notified the AMS support group that the coverage of `amsmath` needs to be updated.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the heads up! The documentation on ams.org has been updated to the version found on CTAN.